# 'PointerWrapper' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, constructor, compiler-errors

im trying to run a splashkit project but this error keeps popping up and won't let me run the file and gives me this error. Anyone know how to fix this?

heres my program.cs

```
using SplashKitSDK;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Window("Window Title... to change", 800, 600);

        SplashKit.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

this is a part of the splashkit.cs file

```
    public Window(string caption, int width, int height) : base ( SplashKit.OpenWindow(caption, width, height), false )
    { }

        public Window(nint ptr) => this.ptr = ptr; //this is where the error is

        protected internal override void DoFree()
    {
        // System.Console.WriteLine("TODO: Free!");
        SplashKit.CloseWindow(this);
    }
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzr4x.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoCRs.png)

tried the fixes given by visual studio but did not solve the issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).